# Ways to optimize the runtime of x86 assembly subroutine for collatz conjecture

Tags: assembly, collatz

I'm trying to optimize the runtime of the code that I wrote for computing the number of iterations it takes to reach 1 in the collatz conjecture

Here is my psudeocode for this

```
int threexplusone(int x){
    if(x == 1){
      return 0;
    }else{
      if(x % 2 == 0){
        return (threexplusone(x/2)+1);
      }else{
        return (threexplusone(3*x+1)+1);
      }
    }
}
```

Here is my assembly code

```
threexplusone:
    push rbx        ;store the rbx to stack
    mov rax, 0      ;store the base case
    cmp rdi, 1      ;compare the input with 1
    je done         ;finished the loop if equal to 1
    jmp threexplusone_recursive ;jump to the recursion

threexplusone_recursive:
    push rax
    mov rdx,0
    mov rax,rdi
    mov rbx,2
    idiv rbx
    cmp rdx, 0      ;compare to check if the remainder is 0
    mov rbx, rax
    pop rax
    je  even        ;start the even instruction

odd:
    imul rdi,3      ;multiply x by 3
    add rdi, 1      ;add x by 1
    xor rax, rax
    call threexplusone  ;do the recursion
        
    inc rax     ;add the result by one
    jmp done
    
    
even:
    sar rdi,1       ;divided the input by 2
    xor rax,rax
    call threexplusone  ;do the recursion

    inc rax         ;add the result by one
    jmp done        ;

        ;

done:
    pop rbx
    ret
```

What could be the possible way of optimizing this code？ Thanks

Comment: Convert from recursion to a loop. Check the least significant bit of `x` to see if it's even rather than doing an expensive division. Use `lea rdi, [rdi*2+rdi+1]` to multiply by 3 and add one.

Comment: I've linked two questions that discuss ways to implement this Collatz function efficiently for amd64.  It's a surprisingly common question.

Comment: `idiv rbx` for dividing by 2??!?!??  Yeah, that's the first problem I addressed in my answer on the linked duplicate.  *Never* use `div` or `idiv` to divide by a known power of 2.